# Can the enemies see your camera light?

Tags: outlast

When in pitch black, can the enemies see the light from your camera if you have it pulled up?

Answer (score 3):

From what I've seen when playing the game, no. You can be right in front of the person and be shining that thing in their face and it seems like they still won't notice it.